# Assign DataSourceObject as datasource to Dynamically created gridviews

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dynamic

I am using VS2015 and C#.

In my web app I am creating few GridViews dynamically. No. of GridViews created at run time depends on data (so can be 1 or 2 or any no).

So it's in loop. I want to assign `DataSourceObject` as data source to each GridView like:

```
i=1;

DataRow Myrow;

foreach (DataRow row in dtSection.Rows)
{
    Myrow = row;

    GridView grid = new GridView();

    grid.id = "grid" + i;

    grid.datasource = "data" + i;

    ObjectDataSource dataSource = new ObjectDataSource();
    dataSource.ID = "data" + i;
    dataSource.SelectMethod = "GetTable";
    dataSource.TypeName = "MyNameSpace.MyClass";

    i = i + 1;
}
```

My `GetTable` method which returns DataTable as data source for each grid:

```
public DataTable GetTable()
{
    DataTable dtpage = new DataTable();
    dtpage = ReportDataTable.Clone();  // My another data table from which I am selecting few rows
    DataRow[] rowArray = ReportDataTable.Select("title = '" + Myrow[0].ToString() + "'");

    foreach (DataRow row1 in rowArray)
    {
        dtpage.ImportRow(row1);
    }

    return dtpage;
}
```

For me its not working properly. `GetTable` method executing after the first loop finished i.e. after creating all grids. So When it finally executes method `Myrow` is null and it gives null exception.

How to make it happen so it will assign correctly like:

```
grid1.datasource = data1,  grid2.datasource = data2 .... etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it :)

Added selectparameters to ObjectDataSource.

Now its working for me.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtSection.Rows)
{
    Myrow = row;

    GridView grid = new GridView();

    grid.id = "grid" + i;

    grid.datasourceid = "data" + i;

            ObjectDataSource dataSource = new ObjectDataSource();

            Parameter pm = new Parameter();
            pm.Type = TypeCode.String;
            pm.Name = "title";
            pm.DefaultValue = row[0].ToString();

            dataSource.ID = "data" + i;
            dataSource.SelectMethod = "GetTable";           
            dataSource.SelectParameters.Clear();
            dataSource.SelectParameters.Add(pm);
            dataSource.TypeName = "InternalAuditInspection.ManageGraphReport";
            dataSource.Select();
            dataSource.DataBind();

i = i+1;

}
        public DataTable GetTable(String title)
        {
            DataTable dtpage = new DataTable();
            dtpage = ReportDataTable.Clone();
            DataRow[] rowArray = ReportDataTable.Select("title ='"+ title + "'");

            foreach (DataRow row1 in rowArray)
            {
                dtpage.ImportRow(row1);
            }

            return dtpage;
        }
```